# How do I find old questions asked by users who are still active?

Tags: support, old-questions, data-explorer

Can someone make me a data explorer query that finds questions asked a while ago, by users who continue to be active on the site? (Active within the last month or so.)

Comment: That may result in lots of questions. Do you have any more requirements like sort questions by score, include/exclude questions with accepted answers, questions with/without answers, questions with specific tags...?

Comment: @Trilarion I plan on combining some queries I already have. I have enough SQL skills to combine stuff. I might have been able to write this on my own, but this way I learn some more advanced SQL techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/467297) does some of the trickery you asked for:

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.creationdate
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
where p.posttypeid = 1 -- Q
and u.lastaccessdate > dateadd(m, -1, getdate()) -- users active less then a month ago
and p.creationdate > dateadd(d, -60, getdate()) -- asked less then 60 days ago
and p.closeddate is not null -- not closed
and p.answercount = 0  -- no answers
and p.score > 0 -- postive score
```

Feel free to fork it and adapt it for your exact use case.

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Monday.

Comment: Thanks. I should definitely be able to use this. You might want to make it `and p.creationdate < dateadd(d, -60, getdate())` because I asked for OLD questions :)

Comment: @Laurel yeah, I was not sure how to interpret a while ago but your take on it will work.

Comment: small typo: closeddate has to be null;  [my version](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/467481/how-do-i-find-old-questions-asked-by-users-who-are-still-active)